# kickstart ESXi vim-cmd hostsvc/enable_ssh : 503 service unavailable

Tags: vmware-esxi, kickstart

In my vmware ESXi kickstart file, the following command `vim-cmd hostsvc/enable_ssh` failed with the error message - `503 service unavailable`.

After Vmware ESXi kickstart installation, if I type the command from shell, I get the same error message three times. After that, the command runs successfully! Do you have any ideas?

Last week, the same kickstart file worked great with no error, and ssh was activated on Vmware ESXi 5.1.

Thanks in advance,

Joris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to localhost dns query on my local network, initiated by my VMware ESXi during the kickstart installation. Indeed, a DNS server was temporally down, and the DNS query timed out.

Theses queries delays VMware service start and induces the command failed (503 service unavailable).

The /etc/hosts file contains « localhost.localdomain» but not localhost…

To solve my problem, I do the following:

```
%pre --interpreter=busybox
Echo > /etc/resolv.conf
Echo “127.0.0.1 localhost  ... ..."
```

I didn't need DNS service.

Joris